# Azure ASP.NET Core web api returns 404 for proxied multipart/form-data request

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to Azure and trying to set up my nextjs client app and my ASP.NET Core backend app. Everything seems to play well now, except for file uploads. It's working on localhost, but in production the backend returns a 404 web page (attached image) before reaching the actual API endpoint. I've also successfully tested to make a multipart/form-data POST request in Postman from my computer.

[image: 404 Response]

The way I implemented this is that I'm proxying the  upload from the browser through an api route (client's server side) to the backend. I have to go via the client server side to append a Bearer token from a httpOnly cookie.

I've enabled CORS in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCors(builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod(); });
```

The frontend and backend apps are running in individual services and I've tried to enable CORS in the Azure portal as well, but there I could only allow origins, not headers and methods? The error message doesn't indicate CORS problems, but I just wanted make sure..

As far as I can see the requests look good, with correct URLs and origins. I suspect I'm missing some config in azure, but I didn't get any further by following the hints in the error message.

Any suggestions to what may cause this? Or where I can start looking. I'm not quite sure where to look for log output for this issue.

Comment: Need more details. after file is uploaded from the browser, does it reach your webserver and any error thrown or logged before reaching your asp.net backend app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working. I figured the host header in the proxy http request was unchanged. I only changed the URL for the proxy request, but I solved it by setting the host manually as well. This also explains why it was working at localhost, since both the client and backend was running at the same host.